# flickity add class to previous slide

Tags: vue.js, slider, carousel, flickity

How can I add a class for previous flickity slide?
I need them to fade out. I'm using Vue.js with npm installed flickity.
Current slide has `.is-selected` class, so maybe I can add somehow `.is-prev, .is-next` classes dynamically?

Comment: provide more code